# Using IP addresses from IP pool given by ISP

Tags: router, ipv4, nat, subnet, ip-address

My ISP says that it can provide an optic fiber connection with a pool of 4 static IP addresses (subnet `255.255.255.248` i think).
My question is that if I get that connection,
1 ip will be used for network
1 for default gateway
1 for broadcast.
So I will get only 1 usable ip address, while other internet plan have only 1 static ip address and cost less. So what is the benefit of pool of 4 ip?

**EDIT**

netmask would be `255.255.255.252`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on exactly how the ISP provides them to you.  You may have "4 DHCP addresses", a  "routed" /30, or a "connected" /29.

For example, Time Warner Cable (business class) allows 4 devices to use DHCP to get an address. (similar to residential service that's limited to one)

"routed" is what you'd see where you have a WAN side and LAN side. This is the traditional "lease line" model where the T1/DS3/etc. ISP side has an independent address to which the static address block is routed; from there they can be assigned as a LAN or NAT'd individually (the firewall situation Bulki mentions.)

"connected" would be where the ISP provides your LAN (i.e. a data center, or the "routed" example where you don't control the router)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide a link from where I can get information about these 3 types of connections.

Answer (score 4):

> subnet 255.255.255.248

which gives you 8 addresses, 1 for network, 1 for broadcast, 1 for default gateway => you can use up to 5 addresses. Sometimes (mostly in datacenter environment) more addresses are reserved for FHRP.

---

example:
8.8.8.0/29,
8.8.8.0 is network address, 
8.8.8.7 is broadcast address
8.8.8.6 is default gateway address
you can use 8.8.8.[1-5] as host ip addresses.

---

If, however, your ISP gives you a subnet with 4 addresses at all, which is /30 (netmask 255.255.255.252), you can still use one address as host address (the rest are broadcast, network, and default gateway addresses). This option gives you no advantage over "other internet plan" speaking in terms of address count.

TL;DR: subnet 255.255.255.248 gives you up to 5 usable ip addresses, subnet 255.255.255.252 gives you one.

Answer (score 2):

Normally a /30 is used for 2 addresses. That is correct. However on firewalls this is often again divided in /32's so you can use them seperately. It's like an ISP gets a range from it's provider (ex: RIPE) and then divides these adresses via subnetting to their customers. The same principle can be applied to this /30 by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When your isp provided with four static public ips .

1 - you can use for egress interfàe ip for your perimeter làyer3 device

You will configure default route pointing towards isp gateway in perimeter làyer3 device

Ip route 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 pointing towards isp gateway

I

Remaining three ip address are your inventory . Your càn use for destination nàtting purpose for hosting àny application or you an use as per you requirement...